# Not showing appropriate NSDate time in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I accessing a web service after i parsing that that code i got AiringTime of US EST 2011-10-17T14:00:00Z remaining  code i written below

```
NSString *string = [[dateArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"AiringTime"];
NSArray *stringArray1 = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"T"];
NSString *string1 = [stringArray1 objectAtIndex:1];
NSArray *stringArray2 = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"Z"];
NSString *dateInString = [stringArray2 objectAtIndex:0];

nowDate =[stringArray1 objectAtIndex:0];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];

NSDate *dateFromString =  [formatter dateFromString:dateInString];
[formatter release];
```

above NSDate *dateFromString given me appropriate output like 14:00 from morning to evening 6:30PM. After evening 6:30PM dateFromString gave mi nil value even though dateInString has an appropriate value?? Why? and How it happen?

I mean,
    NSDate *dateFromString =  [formatter dateFromString:dateInString];
this line not working, dateFromString gave me nil output. 
I wasting my last 3 days evening time due to this strange problem. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the string look like when you get a nil value

Comment: Are you interested in the time only, or do you want the full date? What do you expect `dateFromString` to hold? Because at the moment you are passing it a formatted time string only (e.g. 14:00:00). How is the formatter supposed to return a valid date object from that?

Comment: @jrturton, yes i am interested only in time string.

Comment: @jbat100, the string look like same that given me at morning to 6:00PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1), the example format is exactly the one you are dealing with.

Instead of splitting and manipulating the string yourself, simply do the following:

```
NSString *string = [[dateArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"AiringTime"];
//Time in according to GMT+
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *dateFromString =  [formatter dateFromString:string];
[formatter release];
```

If you are only interested in the time then NSDate is meaningless. What do you want to *do* with it afterwards?

Comment: i m sorry asking u stupid question but i want to know my time zone is US EST so how i set my time according to your code?

Comment: Not a stupid question - I thought from your comment that it was GMT. You can use [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] if that is your local time zone, or [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"name here"] (sorry, I don't know the official name for US EST off the top of my head)

Comment: sorry again, above code time is according 24 hrs yeah 12 hrs?

Comment: That might depend on your locale. See setting the en_US_POSIX locale in the page I linked to.